# Add attachments to Outlook email based on filepaths in filtered table range

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to add the files listed in a filtered table to an Outlook email body as attachments.

The code creates an email and adds table2 to the body.

If I filter the table, it will copy the filtered part of the table (what I want).

I would like the files listed in the filtered table to be added as attachments as well.

For example, I have filepaths in Column "G", let's say, G2 to G10, and I filter my table to display G3, G4 and G5, I would like the files listed in those cells added as attachments to the Outlook email.

The following line only adds the file listed on cell G2 no matter how I filter the table:

```
.attachments.Add "C:\RemoteAMBA\bin\SoftTokens\" & Range("g2").Value
```

Full code:

```vb
Sub Soft_Token_Distribution()
Dim outlook As Object
Dim newEmail As Object
Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object
Dim path As String

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

With newEmail
    .To = Sheet4.Range("L2").Text
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "ADD SUBJECT LINE HERE"
    .HTMLBody = "Hi, <br/><br/> As part of your <b> Create, Modify or Terminate SOW Contingent Worker </b> ServiceNow request for the below user, you requested Remote Access for the user. <br/><br/> Vendor Remote Access has been provisioned for this user. Please share the attached documents with the user so that they can configure their Vendor Remote Access. <br/><br/> Regards,"
   
    .attachments.Add "C:\RemoteAMBA\bin\SoftTokens\" & Range("g2").Value
    
    Set .SendUsingAccount = outlook.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
    
    .Display
    Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor
    
    Sheet4.Range("Table2[#All]").Copy
    
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = 316
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = 
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
    
    .Display
    '.Send
    Set pageEditor = Nothing
    Set xInspect = Nothing
End With

Set newEmail = Nothing
Set outlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is with the first line of code as it needs to filter the attachments based on the cells (Column "G") currently being displayed on the table.

.attachments.Add "C:\RemoteAMBA\bin\SoftTokens\" & Range("g2").Value
    
   
.Display
Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor
    
Sheet4.Range("Table2[#All]").Copy
    
pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = 316
pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)

Comment: What is the range of cells, G2 is only one cell?

Comment: The range of cells will vary but let's suppose  the range is G2:G10

Comment: did you want to attach the whole table and then paste the filtered table in to the body of the email? OR attach both the whole table and the filtered table?

Comment: The code is already copying the filtered table to the body of the Outlook email, so no changes are needed there. What I want is the code to also include the same attachments/path location listed on the filtered table (attachments are listed on column "G") and attach them to the outlook email

Comment: try this Sub test(): Set range1 = Range("g3:g10"): For Each cell In range1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible): MsgBox cell.Value: Next: End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the calls in question and call `newEmail.Attachments.Add` for each cell.